# Angular (IONIC) - Cannot read property 'getInfos' of undefined

Tags: angular

I was following a "tutorial" where I can read an API from Angular.
When I open my Symfony, I can read the endpoint with a GET and a POST (with Postman too).

```
  ngOnInit() {
    try {
      return this.infosService.getAllInfos()
          .subscribe(data => this.infos = data);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log("TEST KO");
    }
  }
```

In my infos.service.ts file, I got these lines to get the datas but only call getAllInfos in this example:

```
  apiUrl='Http://localhost:8000/api/info';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
    getInfos() {
        return this._http.get<Infos[]>(this.apiUrl);
    }

    getAllInfos() {
        return this._http.get<Infos[]>(this.apiUrl);
    }
```

Thanks: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-hnz4eg?devtoolsheight=33&file=app/infos-render/infos-render.component.html

Where did I mess up?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't import HttpClientModule and not correct InfosService providing in app.module:

> ```
> import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from "@angular/core";
> import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
> import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from "ionic-angular";
> import { MyApp } from "./app.component";
> import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
>
> import { AboutPage } from "../pages/about/about";
> import { ContactPage } from "../pages/contact/contact";
> import { HomePage } from "../pages/home/home";
> import { TabsPage } from "../pages/tabs/tabs";
> import { InfosService } from "./services/infos/infos.service";
> import { InfosRenderComponent } from "./infos-render/infos-render.component";
>
> @NgModule({
>   declarations: [
>     MyApp,
>     AboutPage,
>     ContactPage,
>     HomePage,
>     TabsPage,
>     InfosRenderComponent
>   ],
>   imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp), HttpClientModule],
>   bootstrap: [IonicApp],
>   entryComponents: [MyApp, AboutPage, ContactPage, HomePage, TabsPage],
>   providers: [
>     { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
>     InfosService
>   ]
> })
> export class AppModule {}
> ```

or you can see full [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5vkuqt?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)